# How to make the search topology as inactive?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, topology

I tried to clone the existing search and create a new search. Now my both the search services are active. How to make the old one as inactive? I cannot delete the old one without being sure of new one working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search Topology has a specific meaning. It sounds like you're talking about a Search Service Application, instead.

What you can do is unbind the to-be-decomm'ed SSA Proxy from your Web Applications. Validate you can search/search works as expected with your Web Applications. Once validated, delete the old SSA.

Comment: Correct, I am cloning the existing search application, activating it, now I have both the services active.

Comment: In that case, just follow my second paragraph of unbinding the old Search Proxy from the Web App, bind the new one, test, decomm the old SSA.

Answer (score 0):

Look into service application association. You can change the association from old search app to new one, then test when you are good you can just delete the old one.